# Why does is_user_logged_in() return false after redirect from another site?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a WordPress site that redirects to an external payment gateway after a user registers for the site. After the user makes a payment the user is redirected to a page to complete their sign up.

Here is the code used for the redirect:

```
$login_data = array();
$login_data['user_login'] = $email;
$login_data['user_password'] = $password;
$login_data['remember'] = true;
$user = wp_signon($login_data);
if(!is_wp_error($user)){
    wp_set_current_user( $user->ID, $email );
    wp_set_auth_cookie( $user->ID, true, false );
    wp_redirect("https://another_payment_gateway.com");
    exit;
}
```

The user is redirected and fills out the payment form. Upon success the user is redirected to a landing page. If they are not logged in they are shown a dialog for non logged in users. Here is the code on that page:

```
if(is_user_logged_in()){
  $user = wp_get_current_user();
  //code for logged in users
}else{
  //message for non logged in users 
}
```

If I go to the account page it is shown that the user is logged in. But when redirected from a different site is_user_logged_in() returns false. Any insight into this issue would be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

```php
add_action( 'loop_start', 'your_function' );

function your_function() {
  if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo '<li id="text-2" class="hide">';
  } else {
    echo '<li id="text-2">'; 
  }
}
```

Please check with the above hook , will that work for logged-in and non-logged-in user.